# Fix .svn directory permissions

Tags: apache, svn, ubuntu

Any advice on how to correct all the .svn directory (and their contents) permissions in my webroot using the command line (Ubuntu)? I was chowning the files to www-data, but forgot to filter out the .svn directories :p

More detail:

I would like to chown back the .svn directories and their contents to the original owner. The user:group isn't the issue, the recursive command to chown all .svn directories and everything contained within them is what I'm looking for.

Comment: What exactly do you want? The www-data to have permissions to everything but .svn? It might be better to just svn export into your web directory (thereby getting rid of all the .svn stuff).

Comment: I need the svn stuff. I'm not looking to change anything other than the permissions of .svn folders and their contents.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If all you want is to change the ownership on all your .svn directories you could do the following:

```
find /dir/to/repo -name .svn -exec chown user:group -R {} ;
```

Depending on your shell you might need to escape the ; (use \;) and/or the {} (use \{\})

Comment: I found that command yesterday but it doesn't fix the files within the .svn directories

Comment: Did you use the -R switch on chown?

Comment: argh. thank you.. I should have double checked the recursive flag.